# How do I manipulate an ArrayList into my program so that each item can be utilized separately?

Tags: java, eclipse

The `ArrayList` was created off of a file, and there are no issues with that. This is part of my code from my `Helper` class when creating a method to display the results. I know I can't use .toString() for the array list but I don't know how to use it.

Original Code:

```
public static void display(ArrayList<String> shapes) throws FileNotFoundException{
     ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(ArrayList.toString(list)); //This is the problem line.

    while(input.hasNext()){
        String chosenShape = input.nextLine();

        switch (chosenShape.toLowerCase())
        {
        case "rectangle":
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
            rectangle.name = input.nextLine();
            rectangle.setWidth(input.nextDouble());
            rectangle.setLength(input.nextDouble());
            System.out.print(rectangle);
            break;
```

Updated Code:

```
public static void display(ArrayList<String> shapes) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{

    java.util.List<String> list = Arrays.asList("rectangle", "circle","triangle");


    for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++)
        switch (list.get(i).toLowerCase())
        {
        case "rectangle":
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
            rectangle.name = list.get(i+1);
            rectangle.setWidth(Double.valueOf(list.get(i+2)));
            rectangle.setLength(Double.valueOf(list.get(i+3)));
            System.out.print(rectangle);
            i = (i+3);
            break;
```

Errors given: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "triangle".
And when I take out "triangle"... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2

Comment: Use foreach or iterator to iterate on arraylist

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("circle", "rectangle");

        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++ ) {
            switch(list.get(i).toLowerCase())
            {
            case "rectangle":
                // Your rectangle code
                break;
            case "circle":
                // Your circle code
                break;
            default: System.out.println("Default");
            }
        }
    }
```

Or you can use `Java 8 ArrayList foreach()`:

```
list.forEach(s -> {
            switch(s.toLowerCase())
            {
            case "rectangle":
                // Your rectangle code
                break;
            case "circle":
                // Your circle code
                break;
            default: System.out.println("Default");
            }
        });
```

Or you can also use enhanced for loop:

```
for(String s: list) {
            switch(s.toLowerCase())
            {
            case "rectangle":
                // Your rectangle code
                System.out.println("t");
                break;
            case "circle":
                // Your circle code
                break;
            default: System.out.println("Default");
            }
        }
```

**Note:** You need to iterate over each element of `arraylist`. `Scanner` is used to get user input.

Comment: Thank you, i think that helped but I'm still having a number of issues. I put this in my code like you said and added triangle because those are my three shapes. List<String> list = Arrays.asList("circle", "rectangle", "triangle"); I got an error back stating Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "triangle".

Comment: Then I took out the "triangle" to see if that was this issue and I got the error message Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2. I tried to reconvert the Strings to Doubles where needed, I don't know if that caused an issue, I'll edit with my new code.

Comment: @CorinneBerchtold I checked you're updated question. The problem lies in the rectangle part that you added specifically list.get(i+2). The outer loop runs 3 times and then in switch case you have list.get(i+2) which will definitely throw an exception. Secondly you have display method which already have shape list. I am assuming you already have rectangle, triangle etc in that list. You don't need Arrays.asList in that case. It would be great if you add your rectangle model class also. I will check and update answer. This way I will be able to help you in better way. Thanks